# Javascript how to use imported object in function?

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, es6-modules

UPDATED ...

I'm trying to use imported object in my nuxt.config.js
This is Nuxt.js configuration file.

I have this:
seo.js

```
export default {
  link: [
    {
      rel: 'icon',
      type: 'image/x-icon',
      href: '/img/favicon.ico',
    },
  ],
  meta: [
    { 
      charset: 'utf-8' 
    }
  ]
}
```

Then in nuxt.config.js:

```
import seo from './seo'

export default {
  head() {
    return {
        ...seo,
    }
  },
  ... other config setting ...
}
```

Then I'm getting an error: "_seo is not defined"
I'm not trying to export head as function, this is config file and there are more settings.

While this works, nuxt.config.js:

```
import seo from './seo'

export default {
  head: {
        ...seo,
    }
  }
  ... other config settings ...
}
```

It seams that I can't use imported object in function. I'm confused, what is the problem here and how can I use that imported object?

Answer (score 1):

Change you nuxt.config.js to the following

```
import seo from "./seo";

export const head = () => {
  return {
    ...seo
  };
};

export default head;
```

I have put this on a code sandbox, if you look at the console log it is outputting the correct information

https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-almeida-j8dyq?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Thanks Dave! I'm sorry I didn't mention in my question, that nuxt.config.js is Nuxt.js config file, and I don't want to export head as function. I just want to add see to config options. Seo file is more complex too. I edited my question. Sorry for that.

Comment: I just want to add seo to config options.

Answer (score 0):

for such exports, it is recommended to use the *named* export.

```
export const links = [
{
  rel: 'icon',
  type: 'image/x-icon',
  href: '/img/favicon.ico',
},
```

]

And Import it as follow:

```
import {seo} from './seo'
export default {
   head: {
    ...seo,
  }
```

}
}

Comment: Thanks Brhane! I'm sorry I didn't mention in my question, that nuxt.config.js is Nuxt.js config file, and I don't want to export head as function. I just want to add see to config options. Seo file is more complex too. I edited my question. Sorry for that.

Comment: I just want to add seo to config options.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of exporting `head` as a method of the default object, you can directly default export the function

```js
import seo from "./seo";

export default function() {
  return {
    ...seo
  };
};
```

Comment: Thanks jonatjano! I'm sorry I didn't mention in my question, that nuxt.config.js is Nuxt.js config file, and I don't want to export head as function. I just want to add see to config options. Seo file is more complex too. I edited my question. Sorry for that.

Comment: I just want to add seo to config options.